# how can I click button inside UI table view cell (custom cell ) and then goto other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uitableview

I have `MyTableViewCell` class and their .xib

on my `TableViewController` want to click button inside cell and then goto my other `UIViewController` , `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`

from this

```
 class OverviewViewController: UITableViewController 
 { 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
}
```

To this

```
class HistoryController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var MyTable: UITableView! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.MyTable.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HistoryTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "HistoryTableViewCell")


}
```

`historyBtn` in `MyTableViewCell`

an I use that

```
         ....

     cell.historyBtn.tag = indexPath.row 
     cell.historyBtn.addTarget(self, action: "getHistoryList", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

     ....
```

My HistoryList Method

```
    func getHistoryList()
    {
     presentViewController(HistoryController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```

But when go to the `HistoryController` I get this error :

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

MyTableView nil

Comment: You are using storyboard ?

Comment: I have not seen that library @ido07

Comment: can you give me any suggest for develop  multiple page like that library ?

Comment: In that library one example project for the swift is given. Please check that.

Comment: did you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you need delegate for you custom cell

[image]

[image]

after you should use it in action button inside cell

[image]

in your tableView controller you add protocol

[image]

in your tableView controller set delegate to cell

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

   cell.delegate = self;
```

after you can use your delegate method in your tableview controller

```
-(void)selectButtonWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];//or another transition code
}
```

P.S I'm sorry my example on objective-c code but , it is only right way to do what you want.

Comment: you can convert this to swift ı dont know Objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Swift:

You have to write a delegate method within your ViewController containing the tableView like this:

```
protocol PushButtonDelegate {

    func pushBtn()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PushButtonDelegate {

}
```

Within your ViewController you have to define the function pushBtn like this:

```
protocol PushButtonDelegate {

     func pushBtn()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PushButtonDelegate {

     func pushBtn() {

        let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserSettingsVC")            
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Next step is to call the delegate methos within your TableViewCell.swift like this:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate : PushButtonDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func menuBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        delegate?.pushBtn()
    }
}
```

The last step is to set the delegate in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function at ViewController like this:

```
protocol PushButtonDelegate {

    func pushBtn()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PushButtonDelegate {

    func pushBtn() {

    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC4 = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserSettingsVC")
    VC4.title = "Settings"

    self.presentViewController(VC4, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell") as! TableViewCell            
    cell.delegate = self     
    return cell

}
```

DONE. If you need any further help, just let me know.